# ArrayList sorting after remove a specific item

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

i need to sort the elements of an ArrayList oredering from the elements who is next to the removed one.

somethink like this:

if i have
Arraylist list = [ obj1 , obj2 , obj3, obj4 ]

and i remove from the list obj2, i have to remain with a list ordered like this:

Arraylist remainingList = [ obj3, obj4, obj1  ]

i tryed a for cycle with 2 variables that iterates list.size()-1 times
obj is the element i dont need in remainingLIst

```
   for(int i=list.indexOf(obj),  k= 0 ; k<list.size()-1; k++)
    {
        if (i==giocatori.size()) i=0;
        else i++;
        remainingList.add(List.get(i));
    }
```

is there a more efficent way to to this?

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to do. What is the exact problem description?

Comment: This is not obvious how you want to sort the remainingList ? please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: You're using `k < list.size() - 1` as the condition of your for-loop, are you sure you want the `- 1`?

Comment: it is a card game , i have my Players Object inside an ArrayList<Players>.
at the end of a round i have to remove the winning player and let other player keep doing a last round, following the order

Comment: So, you're looking to place any players before the removed player, to the end of the list?

Comment: @Reilas that's what i wanted to ask, thank you. I m'not that good at summarizing :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating too many variable to track your iteration, creating new List from existing using subList method might be efficient. For sake of simplicity, I am taking list of integer below:

```
List<Integer> integerList = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
Integer objToRemove = 5;
int removeObjectIndex = integerList.indexOf(objToRemove);
List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<>(integerList.subList(removeObjectIndex + 1, integerList.size()));
finalList.addAll(integerList.subList(0, removeObjectIndex));
System.out.println(finalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the specified player, and place any players that were before that player, to the end of the list.

Keep in mind, this presumes that `player` exists.

```java
void removePlayer(Players player) {
    int indexOf = list.indexOf(player);
    List<Players> sublist = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(0, indexOf));
    remainingList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Iterator<Players> iterator = remainingList.iterator();
    int index = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext() && index <= indexOf) {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        index++;
    }
    remainingList.addAll(sublist);
}
```